# What kind of certificate do you need to digitally sign an .exe?

Tags: windows, certificate, setup, digital-signature

I want to digitally sign a setup.exe file for Windows.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee290833(v=vs.100).aspx I need a "certificate" to do so.

What kind of certificate do I need and how do I get one?

Comment: You can either use a self-signed certificate or a code signing certificate.  Visual Studio can can create the self-signed certificate and you can use the same tool that you do that to actually use the code signing certificate to sign the executable with either certificate.  Don't use the deprecated method, you will limit your signed application, to being trusted to older versions of Windows

Comment: If you are using it for internal or testing purposes, you can use code signing self-signed certificate. It can be easily created using PowerShell. You can refer this doc: https://blog.admindroid.com/how-to-create-self-signed-certificate-using-powershell/#Create_code-signing_certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details depend on the toolchain used by your installation routine. The linked article is for Visual Studio 2010, and it uses an older process described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx
This method requires the makecert and pvf2pfx utilities from the windows development kit.

That approach has been deprecated so unless you are working with legacy tools, you want to use the new methodology described here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing
This method uses Powershell to create a self-signed cert and add it to the system certificate catalog.

Both links above provide information on the AppManifest.xml, and on how to use these certificates for signing code packages.